# Android: Eclipse LogCat shows destroyed activity logs

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, logcat, android-logcat

I have a main activity which calls another activity.
I want the second activity to be completely destroyed when back button is pressed.
The onDestroy method is always called when I press back button, but in Eclipse LogCat I still see logs belonging to the destroyed activity (I set them on screen orientation change).
Is it an Eclipse bug or my second activity is never destroyed?

This is my PhotoActivity, called after CameraActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo);
[…]
    OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) 
    { 
     @Override
     public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) 
     {

      mDeviceOrientation = orientation;

      int norientation = 90*Math.round(mDeviceOrientation / 90); 

         if(norientation == 360)
         {
             norientation = 0;
         }

        Log.d("photo","orientation function:"+norientation);
     }
    };

    if(mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation())
    {
     mOrientationEventListener.enable();
    }


}
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("photo","destroy");
}
```

And this is my LogCat:

```
    09-03 09:14:54.630: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:55.630: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:55.635: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:55.834: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:55.834: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:56.235: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:56.235: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:56.434: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:56.434: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:56.635: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:56.635: D/Sensor(26901): Landscape
    09-03 09:14:56.635: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:56.830: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:56.830: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:57.030: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:57.030: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:57.234: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:57.234: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:57.434: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:57.434: D/Sensor(26901): Portrait
    09-03 09:14:57.434: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:57.635: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:57.635: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:57.835: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:57.835: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:58.034: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:58.034: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:58.234: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:58.234: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:58.434: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:58.434: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:58.634: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:58.634: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:58.835: D/orientation(26901): orientation:270
    09-03 09:14:58.835: D/photo(26901): orientation function:270
    09-03 09:14:59.040: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:59.040: D/Sensor(26901): Landscape
    09-03 09:14:59.040: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:14:59.235: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:14:59.235: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:39.240: W/KeyCharacterMap(26901): No keyboard for id 0
    09-03 09:15:39.240: W/KeyCharacterMap(26901): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
    09-03 09:15:39.700: D/camera(26901): onrestart:true
    09-03 09:15:39.710: D/camera(26901): camera:android.hardware.Camera@4056a410
    09-03 09:15:39.725: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:39.725: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:39.725: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:39.725: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:39.760: E/Surface(26901): Surface::init token -2 identity 2344
    09-03 09:15:39.760: D/camera(26901): camera1:android.hardware.Camera@4056a410
    09-03 09:15:39.760: D/camera(26901): camera:android.hardware.Camera@4056a410
    09-03 09:15:40.780: D/camera(26901): w=480-h=800
    09-03 09:15:40.795: D/camera(26901): rotazione
    09-03 09:15:40.795: D/camera(26901): rotation0
    09-03 09:15:40.800: D/camera(26901): parH=800-parW=480
    09-03 09:15:40.825: D/camera(26901): W=800-H=480
    09-03 09:15:41.320: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:41.320: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:41.320: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:41.320: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:41.320: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:41.320: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
                          09-03 09:15:41.390: D/photo(26901): destroy
    09-03 09:15:41.684: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:41.684: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:41.885: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:41.885: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:42.684: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:42.684: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:42.884: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:42.884: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:43.084: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:43.084: D/Sensor(26901): Landscape
    09-03 09:15:43.084: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:43.285: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:43.285: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:43.485: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:43.485: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:43.685: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:43.685: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
    09-03 09:15:43.885: D/orientation(26901): orientation:0
    09-03 09:15:43.885: D/photo(26901): orientation function:0
```

As you can see the photo activity is destroyed (I indented more the destroy log), but the log "orientation function: degrees" is continuing appearing as I move the phone.

Comment: Are there new logs getting added AFTER the onDestroy event from the second activity?

Comment: yes, and I don't understand why. Even when application is closed (not a force close, just using back button), logs of that activity are getting added.

Comment: Please post your logcat statements and your relevant code so we can see what is happening. (For what it is worth, there is no Android glitch like this that I know of, so this should be fixable.)

Comment: It sounds like you have references that are held open.  Be sure that you are cleaning up all references, especially any listeners.